# Cannot save data to a cell using autosave with handsontable

Tags: jquery, save, undefined, handsontable

I am encountering some problems when saving data from a cell with hansontable and could use some suggestions.

The problems are:

1. Autosave 1 cell sends undefined.
2. Autosave multiple cells also passes undefined.
3. On click save button the console shows : `Save error. POST method is not allowed on GitHub Pages. Run this example on your own server to see the success message`

**code:**

```
<script>
          var $container = $("#excel");
          var $console = $("#excelconsole");
          var $parent = $container.parent();
          var autosaveNotification;
          $container.handsontable({
            startRows: 1,
            startCols: <?=$num_rName+1?>,//count room type name from db
            rowHeaders: true,
            //colHeaders: ['Date/Room Types', 'Year', 'Price'],
            colHeaders: <?echo json_encode($_array);?>,
            minSpareCols: 0,
            minSpareRows: 1,
            contextMenu: true,
            onChange: function (change, source) {
              if (source === 'loadData') {
                return; //don't save this change
              }
              if ($parent.find('input[name=autosave]').is(':checked')) {
                clearTimeout(autosaveNotification);
                $.ajax({
                  url: "inc/excel_save.php",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  type: "POST",
                  data: change, //contains changed cells' data
                  complete: function (data) {
                    $console.text('Autosaved (' + change.length + ' cell' + (change.length > 1 ? 's' : '') + ')');
                    autosaveNotification = setTimeout(function () {
                      $console.text('Changes will be autosaved');
                    }, 1000);
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          });
          var handsontable = $container.data('handsontable');

          $parent.find('button[name=load]').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
              url: "inc/excel_load.php",
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'GET',
              success: function (res) {
                handsontable.loadData(res.data);
                $console.text('Data loaded');
              }
            });
          });

           $parent.find('button[name=save]').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
              url: "inc/excel_save.php",
              data: {"data": $("#excel").handsontable('getData')}, 
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'POST',
              success: function (res) {
                if (res.result === 'ok') {
                  $console.text('Data saved');
                }
                else {
                  $console.text('Save error');
                }
              },
              error: function () {
                $console.text('Save error. POST method is not allowed on GitHub Pages. Run this example on your own server to see the success message.');
              }
            });
          });

          $parent.find('input[name=autosave]').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              $console.text('Changes will be autosaved');
            }
            else {
              $console.text('Changes will not be autosaved');
            }
          });
        </script>
```

**excel_save.php**

```
<?
foreach($_POST as $key=>$val){//test the var passed
    echo "$key=$val<br />";
}
?>
```

**data loaded**
[image]

**save with undefined**
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Change

`data: change,`

to

`data : {changes: change},`

Found it [here](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/commit/4cd99d2d0ac2db9cc0086d82ec1acb3a7a0b79ea)